# Solução para transição de telas

Tags: jquery

Tenho um site one-page que vai seguir o seguinte padrão:

```
<section id="home"></section>
<section id="empresa"></section>
<section id="mapa"></section>
<section id="contato"></section>
```

Para fazer a transição de telas, geralmente eu uso o `scrollTop`, porém eu tenho que informar a posição de cada **section** em `px`. E não é isso que eu quero.
Tem alguma forma de eu fazer scrollar direto para a **id** desejada, ou algo do gênero?

O que uso atualmente:

```
$('.home').click(function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '0'
    }, 700);
    setHistory('MEUSITE- Home', site + '/home');
});
$('.empresa').click(function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '855px'
    }, 700);
    setHistory('MEUSITE- Empresa', site + '/empresa');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(this).offset().top`. `offset()` vai obter a coordenadas do elemento, enquanto `$(this).offset().top` vai pegar a distância do elemento clicado na posição vertical. No animate você usa o offset do elemento para mover a tela. Fiz um [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7a7xe7za/) para ilustrar.

```
$('.home').click(function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 700);
    setHistory('MEUSITE- Home', site + '/home');
});
$('.empresa').click(function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 700);
    setHistory('MEUSITE- Empresa', site + '/empresa');
});
```

---

Você pode fazer de forma mais simples usando a combinação ID e CLASS. Quando clicar no `<section id=" ...">` ele vai animar até a div correspondente sem precisar definir item por item. Para essa forma fiz outro [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfz0q7sb/)

```
$('section').click(function () {
    section = $(this).attr( 'id' );
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('.' + section).offset().top }, 700);
    setHistory('MEUSITE- Empresa', site + '/empresa');
});

// botões
<section id="home">home</section>
<section id="empresa">empresa</section>

// conteúdo
<div class="home">home</div>
<div class="empresa">empresa</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

(http://jsfiddle.net/NadirZenith/ocopr9kb/1/)

pode usar este script jquery que faz um scroll até a ancora na mesma pagina

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                                  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
                                        var target = $(this.hash);
                                        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                                        if (target.length) {
                                              $('html,body').animate({
                                                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70//offset from top fixed menu??
                                              }, 1000);
                                              return false;
                                        }
                                  }
                            });
```

com este tipo de ancoras

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa">empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mapa">mapa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato">contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

e usar suas secçoes da mesma forma:

```
<section id="home"></section>
<section id="empresa"></section>
<section id="mapa"></section>
<section id="contato"></section>
```